# Filter an array of objects based on filter criteria in another array of objects: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, filter

I wish to filter `myArray` based on criteria mentioned in `myFilter`.
The keys of myFilter are defined and could be accessed using `myFilter.field`, `myFilter.value` where as key:value of `myArray` are unknown.
We might have to iterate over each object in `myArray` to first match the myArray [key] with `myFilter.field` and then to that myArray [key] to myFilter.value.

That should be an AND logic

```js
myArray = [{
    make: "Honda",
    model: "CRV",
    year: "2017"
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Camry",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Camaro",
    year: "2020"
  }
]

myFilter = [{
    field: "make",
    value: "Chevy",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    field: "year",
    value: "2020",
    type: "date"
  }
];


// Expected OutPut:
myArray = [{
  make: "Chevy",
  model: "Camaro",
  year: "2020"
}]


var tempArray = [];
const keysToMatch = myFilter.length;
let matchedItems = [];
myArray.forEach((data) => {
  matchedItems = [];
  let itemsToFind = Object.values(data);
  myFilter.forEach((filterItem) => {
    if (itemsToFind.indexOf(filterItem.value) != -1) {
      matchedItems.push("matched");
    }
  });
  //check if everything matched
  if (matchedItems.length === keysToMatch) {
    tempArray.push(data);
  }
});

console.log(tempArray);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for asking. What have you tried ?

Comment: `const myNewArray = myArray.filter((car) => myFilter.every((filter) => car[filter.field] === car[filter.value]));` should be almost there.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT: Yes, I have posted it as a answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal for loop and array filter. Define a variable `filteredArray` and use for loop to iterate  `myFilter`. During each iteration create a variable `k` whose value will be set to the filtered array. So at the first step the initial value of `k` will be the `myArray` and `k` will be filtered and the filtered value will be set to `filteredArray`. During second iteration and so on the value of `k` will be set to the first filtered array

```js
let myArray = [{
    make: "Honda",
    model: "CRV",
    year: "2017"
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Camry",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Camaro",
    year: "2020"
  }
]

let myFilter = [{
    field: "make",
    value: "Chevy",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    field: "year",
    value: "2020",
    type: "date"
  }
];
let filteredArray;

for (let i = 0; i < myFilter.length; i++) {
  let k = filteredArray !== undefined ? filteredArray : myArray
  if (myFilter[i].field === 'make') {
    filteredArray = k.filter(item => item[myFilter[i].field] === myFilter[i].value)
  } else if (myFilter[i].field === 'year') {
    filteredArray = k.filter(item => item[myFilter[i].field] === myFilter[i].value)
  }

}
console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: Since myArray could be anything cannot do `item.make` or `item.year`. It has to be general

Comment: We have to iterate over each object, instead of picking manually `if (myFilter[i].field === 'make') {`

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempArray = [];
const keysToMatch = myFilter.length;
let matchedItems = [];
myArray.forEach((data) => {
    matchedItems = [];
    let itemsToFind = Object.values(data);
    myFilter.forEach((filterItem) => {
        if (itemsToFind.indexOf(filterItem.value) != -1) {
            matchedItems.push("matched");
        }
    });
    //check if everything matched
    if (matchedItems.length === keysToMatch) {
        tempArray.push(data);
    }
});

console.log(tempArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should theoretically work, but for some reason doesn't (returns an empty array). I'm hoping for some other reader's heads up to make it work! Feel free to edit.

```js
myArray = [{
    make: "Honda",
    model: "CRV",
    year: "2017"
  },
  {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Camry",
    year: "2020"
  },
  {
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Camaro",
    year: "2020"
  }
]

myFilter = [{
    field: "make",
    value: "Chevy",
    type: "string"
  },
  {
    field: "year",
    value: "2020",
    type: "date"
  }
];


const myNewArray = myArray.filter((car) => myFilter.every((filter) => car[filter.field] === car[filter.value]));

console.log(myNewArray);
```

Comment: it doesn't print anything

Comment: Which is what I wrote in the text of my answer. Please read. I'm certain the code is almost there, but wasn't able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit over complicated for what you need, but it works.

```js
myArray = [
    {
        make: "Honda", 
        model: "CRV",
        year: "2017"
    },
    {
        make: "Toyota", 
        model: "Camry",
        year: "2020"},
    {    
        make: "Chevy", 
        model: "Camaro",
        year: "2020"}
    ]

    myFilter = [
        {
            field: "make",
            value: "Chevy",
            type: "string"
        },
        {
            field: "year",
            value: "2020",
            type: "date"
        }
    ];
         //only return those that return true
var newArray = myArray.filter(car => {
 var temp = true;
    //iterate over your filters
 for (var i = 0; i < myFilter.length; i++) {
        //if any filters result in false, then temp will be false
  if (car[myFilter[i].field] != myFilter[i].value) {
   temp = false;
  }
 }
 if (temp == true) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```