# Why does filtering an array of objects with multiple criteria return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

Let's suppose we have an array of objects named cars:

```
var cars = [

  {color: 'Black', horsePower: 120, type: 'suv'},
  {color: 'Red', horsePower: 90, type: 'cabriolet'},
  {color: 'Yellow', horsePower: 200, type: 'cabriolet'},
  {color: 'Black', horsePower: 350, type: 'suv'}

];
```

I'd like to filter this array passing multiple criteria. For this reason, I created an object of filters.

```
var filters = {

  color: ['Black', 'Red'],
  horsePower: [90],
  type: []

};
```

What I've tried is:

```
var output = cars.filter((elem) => {

  for (var key in filters) {

    if (filters[key].length == 0 || filters[key].indexOf(elem[key]) < 0) {

      return false;

    }

  }

  return true;

});

console.log(output);
```

What I expect to get as result is cars second index, but instead I get an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `type: []` <- remove that. Or change `filters[key].length == 0`

Comment: Is this an assignment? Seems almost exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55852089/filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-filter-criteria-in-another-array-of-objects/55852710#55852710

Comment: @JonasWilms Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `filter[key].length == 0` you `return false`, you probably want to change your condition to:

```
  if(filter[key].length && !filter[key].includes(elem[key]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original filter looks for cars with an empty array for the `type` property. And none of your car objects have that. This should work.

```js
var cars = [

  {color: 'Black', horsePower: 120, type: 'suv'},
  {color: 'Red', horsePower: 90, type: 'cabriolet'},
  {color: 'Yellow', horsePower: 200, type: 'cabriolet'},
  {color: 'Black', horsePower: 350, type: 'suv'}

];

var filters = {

  color: ['Black', 'Red'],
  horsePower: [90]

};

var output = cars.filter((elem) => {

  for (var key in filters) {

    if (filters[key].length == 0 || filters[key].indexOf(elem[key]) < 0) {

      return false;

    }

  }

  return true;

});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do using `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
const cars = [
  {color: 'Black', horsePower: 120, type: 'suv'},
  {color: 'Red', horsePower: 90, type: 'cabriolet'},
  {color: 'Yellow', horsePower: 200, type: 'cabriolet'},
  {color: 'Black', horsePower: 350, type: 'suv'}
];

const filters = {
  color: ['Black', 'Red'],
  horsePower: [90],
  type: []
};

let filteredCars = cars.filter(car => {
  for (const prop in filters) {
    if (filters[prop].length && !filters[prop].includes(car[prop])) return false;
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(filteredCars);
```